# Ruby send e-mail directly to recipients' SMTP servers

Tags: ruby, email

I'd like a ruby gem that would:

1. Go through a list of recipients and gather all their domains
2. For each domain, get the MX record for it to get the SMTP server's address
3. Use those SMTP servers to send an email directly to the recipients (on port 25)

All the solutions out there (like the Mail gem) seem to require you to either have your own SMTP server running, or have an account with some other SMTP provider. I think this is an unnecessary complication.

BTW I've tested this method manually by using the Mail gem and setting the SMTP server to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (which is what gmail.com has as an MX record here) - it successfully sent an email to my gmail account, without needing any auth.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? setting up your own smtp server is trivial. e.g on linux it's `yum install postfix`.

Comment: @MarcB like I said - simplicity.

Comment: What you seem to be missing here is that, if you don't _use_ an SMTP server, you have to _write_ an SMTP server. You have to handle all the complexities of MX lookup, do server-to-server relay instead of client-to-server sending, handle errors properly (which includes queuing and resending), and all kinds of other tricky things. So, unless "it usually works for 2/3rds of my users" is good enough, it's not simpler. Or, more briefly: it's not an unnecessary complication, it's a necessary complication.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving MX records is a non-trivial thing to do, there are all kinds of edge cases you'll encounter, and not all servers work correctly with the Net::SMTP module or Mail gem.

What you probably want is a server like [exim](http://www.exim.org/), [postfix](http://www.postfix-book.com/) or a commercial MTA like [Port25](http://www.port25.com/).

Comment: yes I could use an SMTP server, but I said in my question specifically that I'd rather not do that. The main reason is ease of use - for quick'n'dirty scripts I don't want to set up dependencies like that if the server already doesn't have an MTA - and most of ours servers here don't.

Comment: Sounds like you need an external service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/). I built [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) to solve a lot of these problems and it's really a lot harder than you think. Doing the first 80% of SMTP is fairly easy, but the last 20% is where you get into trouble. Not every MTA is as friendly as google.com.